# Why does this Java based Spring configuration create two instances of a singleton bean?

Tags: java, spring

This occurs when I subclass an `@Configuration` annotated class, and feed this to the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`

These classes below summarize the scenario. Here is the [full source](https://bitbucket.org/bartswen/public-sandbox/raw/master/mult-bean-demo/)

```java
public class Bar {}

public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;
    public Foo(Bar bar) { this.bar = bar; }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "(" + bar + ")"; 
    }
}

@Configuration
public class BaseAppConfig {
    @Bean public Foo foo() { return new Foo(bar()); }
    @Bean public Bar bar() { return new Bar(); }
}

/** Omitting @Configuration here */
public class AppConfig extends BaseAppConfig {
    @Bean @Override public Bar bar() { return new Bar(); }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new
                 AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class)) {
            System.out.println(ctx.getBean(Foo.class).toString());
            System.out.println(ctx.getBean(Bar.class).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This prints two `Bar` instances where I expect to see the same instance two times:

```
Foo@3e9b1010(Bar@6c3708b3)
Bar@6f1fba17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are omitting the `@Configuration` annotation (and because it isn't `@Inherited`)

```
/** Omitting @Configuration here */
public class AppConfig extends BaseAppConfig {
```

Specifying the class in the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new
             AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class)
```

marks it as a **regular** bean class, not a `@Configuration` bean class.

This means that [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) methods are operating in lite mode.

> In contrast to the semantics for bean methods in `@Configuration`
>   classes, **'inter-bean references' are not supported in lite mode.
>   Instead, when one `@Bean`-method invokes another `@Bean`-method in lite
>   mode, the invocation is a standard Java method invocation; Spring does
>   not intercept the invocation via a CGLIB proxy.** This is analogous to
>   inter-@Transactional method calls where in proxy mode, Spring does not
>   intercept the invocation — Spring does so only in AspectJ mode.

Emphasis mine. It means that this that the `bar()` call in

```
return new Foo(bar());
```

is really just calling `bar()` again, it isn't returning the old instance created.

`@Configuration` works by having Spring create a **proxy** of your annotated class which caches the instances returned by `@Bean` factory methods. Since you've removed `@Configuration`, Spring doesn't apply this caching and method calls work normally, in your case returning a new instance.

Comment: Pointing me to the **lite mode** is the real answer to the question. That explains all. I found the specification on the [@Bean documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use direct Bar object creation you should use spring bean management:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseAppConfig {
    @Bean @Autowired public Foo foo(Bar bar) { return new Foo(bar); }
    @Bean public Bar bar() { return new Bar(); }
}
```

See [spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-using-import) for details.